# Python Pandas ETF Time Series Data calculate Trailing Time Periods for each ETF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this time series of returns for 13 ETF funds. I retrieved the monthly historical returns from yfinance from 1/31/2017 to 3/31/2023 - 5.25 years worth of monthly returns.

```
import yfinance as yf
   
tickers_list = ['IVV', 'SPY', 'VOO', 'IWM', 'VTWO', 'VUG', 'MGK', 'IYW', 'SMH','SOXL', 'TECL', 'QQQ', 'IWP']

# Fetch the data
data = yf.download(tickers_list,'2016-12-31', '2023-03-31')['Adj Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()*100

print(data)

[*********************100%***********************]  13 of 13 completed
                 IVV       IWM       IWP        IYW        MGK        QQQ  \
Date                                                                        
2018-01-31       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
2018-02-28 -3.804348 -3.843673 -3.147805   0.406958  -2.802898  -1.292810   
2018-03-31 -2.477626  1.217483 -0.132897  -3.782773  -3.168533  -4.078817   
2018-04-30  0.354223  0.981397 -0.992279  -0.118908   0.409860   0.505834   
2018-05-31  2.410717  6.163581  3.770650   7.499553   4.649504   5.672917   
...              ...       ...       ...        ...        ...        ...   
2022-11-30  5.551971  2.203672  5.362622   6.584629   4.494448   5.544149   
2022-12-31 -5.728810 -6.514127 -6.024389  -8.342131  -8.791930  -9.013667   
2023-01-31  6.272610  9.818770  8.720104  11.008199  10.722378  10.642924   
2023-02-28 -2.532388 -1.723420 -1.023219   0.737697  -1.459161  -0.359781   
2023-03-31  2.290707 -6.564785 -0.550342   9.668837   7.127450   7.701563   

                  SMH       SOXL       SPY       TECL       VOO      VTWO  \
Date                                                                        
2018-01-31        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN   
2018-02-28   0.028171  -2.869297 -3.636015  -4.143532 -3.726007 -3.846475   
2018-03-31  -2.121285  -9.531145 -2.741069 -12.784944 -2.467635  1.133835   
2018-04-30  -6.827767 -20.226410  0.516831  -1.433560  0.346994  1.057984   
2018-05-31  10.323185  35.518003  2.430893  20.565807  2.416443  6.086664   
...               ...        ...       ...        ...       ...       ...   
2022-11-30  20.351965  54.932731  5.559164  14.424575  5.505000  2.146921   
2022-12-31  -9.872508 -29.779331 -5.762832 -24.745740 -5.732450 -6.447269   
2023-01-31  16.832563  50.155129  6.288740  27.737546  6.290209  9.776884   
2023-02-28   0.970050   0.895312 -2.514271  -0.885582 -2.498403 -1.695793   
2023-03-31   9.177110  22.710299  2.266375  27.753202  2.281491 -6.527044   

                  VUG  
Date                   
2018-01-31        NaN  
2018-02-28  -2.921836  
2018-03-31  -2.490675  
2018-04-30   0.274836  
2018-05-31   4.386032  
...               ...  
2022-11-30   4.624219  
2022-12-31  -8.363891  
2023-01-31  10.384313  
2023-02-28  -1.424080  
2023-03-31   5.852608  

[63 rows x 13 columns]
```

I want to retrieve the Market Value, and calculate the 3 Months, 1 YR and 3 Yrs returns for the ETF fund in the Asset ID column. The Market Value I calculated using the ETF prices. The ETF data source and want the output to show like this:

[image]
[image]

This is the script I have so far but is only for one ETF fund - I need to do all 13 funds and lay them out like the output in the picture.

```
enter code here import datetime 
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#As of Date:
VME = '3/31/2023'

#3 Month Return
df_3m = df_data.loc[(df_data['SecurityID'] =='VOO')  & (df_data['Date'] >= pd.to_datetime(VME)-pd.DateOffset(months= 2)) & (df_data['Date'] <= VME)]
df_3mror = (np.prod(df_3m['Return']/100+1)-1)*100

#1 Year Return
df_1yr = df_data.loc[(df_data['SecurityID'] =='VOO')  & (df_data['Date'] >= pd.to_datetime(VME)-pd.DateOffset(months= 11)) & (df_data['Date'] <= VME)]
df_1ror = (np.prod(df_1yr['Return']/100+1)-1)*100

#3 Year Return
df_3yr = df_data.loc[(df_data['SecurityID'] =='VOO')  & (df_data['Date'] >= pd.to_datetime(VME)-pd.DateOffset(months= 35)) & (df_data['Date'] <= VME)]
df_3ror = (np.prod(df_3yr['Return']/100+1)**(12/36)-1)*100
   
print(df_3mror)
print(df_1ror)
print(df_3ror)
```

I hope someone can guide me or able to figure out how to do all ETF funds in one shot and lay it out like in the pic.
Thanks again for all the hep you provide to us new learners.

Comment: Please include  some copy/pasted input data (not an image), alongside what you have so far eg the outputs of your print statements.

Comment: Ciaran - I added the code to data source - I modified the df in excel to show all the tickers in one columns and the returns all in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check for myself with what you provide in your post, but I suggest that you refactor your code by:

- defining an empty dataframe names `results`, for instance
- iterate on etf codes to calculate different returns for each of them
- append results together with Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) at the end of each iteration

Something like this:

```py
results = pd.DataFrame()
for etf in df_data["SecurityID"].unique():
    # 3 Month Return
    df_3m = df_data.loc[
        (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf)
        & (df_data["Date"] >= pd.to_datetime(VME) - pd.DateOffset(months=2))
        & (df_data["Date"] <= VME)
    ]
    df_3mror = (np.prod(df_3m["Return"] / 100 + 1) - 1) * 100

    # 1 Year Return
    df_1yr = df_data.loc[
        (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf)
        & (df_data["Date"] >= pd.to_datetime(VME) - pd.DateOffset(months=11))
        & (df_data["Date"] <= VME)
    ]
    df_1ror = (np.prod(df_1yr["Return"] / 100 + 1) - 1) * 100

    # 3 Year Return
    df_3yr = df_data.loc[
        (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf)
        & (df_data["Date"] >= pd.to_datetime(VME) - pd.DateOffset(months=35))
        & (df_data["Date"] <= VME)
    ]
    df_3ror = (np.prod(df_3yr["Return"] / 100 + 1) ** (12 / 36) - 1) * 100

    results = pd.concat(
        [
            results,
            pd.DataFrame(
                {
                    "AccountNumber": [85150],
                    "AssetID": [etf],
                    "3 Months": [df_3mror],
                    "1 YR ROR": [df_1ror],
                    "3 YRS ROR": [df_3ror],
                }
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Laurent for implementing the code. The lay out resulted with the Asset ID having the the Date, SecurityID and Return as the only underlying ETFs but not the actual 13 ETFs. I was trying to figure something with the code:  **for etf in df_data.columns:***. Does the column "SecurityID" need to be converted to an array or list so it can list the 13 ETFs and then apply the 3M, 1YR and 3YR return calculation.

Comment: Hi Laurent - thanks again for the help - one quick question to add the Market Value for each ETF as of date VME - how can i do that here.

Comment: Hi, without knowing what `df_data` looks like, my guess is that you should add in the final dictionary something like: `"Market Value": [df_data.loc[(df_data.shape["Date"]==pd.to_datetime(VME)) & (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf), "Market value"].value]`. Otherwise, you should post a new question. Cheers.