# Python Time Series Data aggregate based on multiple criterias

Tags: python, pandas

I recently got a solution to my ETF time period returns - thanks to Laurent - solution link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76136825/1332019

What was missed was to add the "Market Value" as of the "Value Date" for the SecurityID.

I have not figure out how to add the "Market Value" to the iteration.

Here is the df_data time series data source:
One account number has multiple funds and some are standalone accounts.

[image]

This is the SUMMARY output I want:

[image]

Here is the solution provided by Laurent and we just need the Market Value and Date with the
correct AccountNumber association.

Here is the code that works so far but just need to add the Market Value and Date and the correct AccountNumber association.
Thanks I again for any help on this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#As of Date:
VME = '3/31/2023'

results = pd.DataFrame()
for etf in df_data["SecurityID"].unique():
    # 3 Month Return
    df_3m = df_data.loc[
        (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf)
        & (df_data["Date"] >= pd.to_datetime(VME) - pd.DateOffset(months=2))
        & (df_data["Date"] <= VME)
    ]
    df_3mror = (np.prod(df_3m["Return"] / 100 + 1) - 1) * 100

    # 1 Year Return
    df_1yr = df_data.loc[
        (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf)
        & (df_data["Date"] >= pd.to_datetime(VME) - pd.DateOffset(months=11))
        & (df_data["Date"] <= VME)
    ]
    df_1ror = (np.prod(df_1yr["Return"] / 100 + 1) - 1) * 100

    # 3 Year Return
    df_3yr = df_data.loc[
        (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf)
        & (df_data["Date"] >= pd.to_datetime(VME) - pd.DateOffset(months=35))
        & (df_data["Date"] <= VME)
    ]
    df_3ror = (np.prod(df_3yr["Return"] / 100 + 1) ** (12 / 36) - 1) * 100

    results = pd.concat(
        [
            results,
            pd.DataFrame(
                {
                    "AccountNumber": [85150],
                    "AssetID": [etf],
                    "3 Months": [df_3mror],
                    "1 YR ROR": [df_1ror],
                    "3 YRS ROR": [df_3ror],
                }
            ),
        ]
    )
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you can add the `market value` to the final dataframe like this:

```py
results = pd.concat(
    [
        results,
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "AccountNumber": [85150],
                "AssetID": [etf],
                "3 Months": [df_3mror],
                "1 YR ROR": [df_1ror],
                "3 YRS ROR": [df_3ror],
                "Market Value": [
                    df_data.loc[
                        (df_data["Date"] == pd.to_datetime(VME))
                        & (df_data["SecurityID"] == etf),
                        "Market Value",
                    ].values
                ][0],
            }
        ),
    ],
    ignore_index=True,
)
```

And add, after and outside the for-loop:

```py
results["Date"] = VME
```

Then:

```py
print(results)
# Output

   AccountNumber AssetID  3 Months  1 YR ROR  3 YRS ROR  Market Value       Date
0          85150     IVV  5.953382  5.953382   1.946333         40539  3/31/2023
1          85150     IWM  0.850816  0.850816   0.282805         17518  3/31/2023
2          85150     IWP  7.019195  7.019195   2.287028          8932  3/31/2023
```

Comment: Laurent - thank you again I was trying to implement your suggestion from last solution. This works great!